# Is $W = \operatorname{span}\{1 +x^2, x^2-4\}$ a subspace of $P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \{ax^2 + bx + c \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $W = \operatorname{span}\{1+x^2, x^2-4\}$. Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

I know a span is a subspace but what is tripping me up is there are no coefficients in $W$. For example, the polynomial of the form $1+x^2$ would not be a subspace because it fails under addition.

Comment: So would I be right to say: W is a span {v1, v2} by an isomorphism from P2 to R3, where:
v1 = (1,0,1) and V2 = (-4,0,1)

Comment: Thus W is a subspace that spans any linear combination of v1 and v2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In general, the span of a set of vectors in a vector space $V$ is (and can be defined as) the smallest subspace of $V$ containing those vectors.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$

By the usual definition, however, we would say that
$$
W = \span\{v_1,v_2\} = \{a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 \mid a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
So, take $x,y \in W$ to be given by $x = a_1v_1 + a_2 v_2$ and $y = b_1 v_1 + b_2 v_2$.  Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary scalar.  With some quick algebra, you can show that
$$
x + y = (a_1 + b_1)v_1 + (a_2 + b_2)v_2 \in W\\
kx = (k\cdot a_1)v_1 + (k \cdot a_2)v_2 \in W
$$
So that $W$ is indeed closed under both addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check three conditions which need to hold for $W$ to be a subspace of $V$:

1.) Is $p_0(x) \in W $ ($(\forall x) \space p_0(x)=0$)? Yes, just make the coefficients of the linear combination zeros.

2.) Is $W \subset V$? Yes, any linear combination of two polynomials of second degree will result in a polynomial of max. second degree.

3.) Does $(\forall x) \space p(x),q(x)\in W \implies \alpha p(x) + q(x) \in W$? It is easy to check this is indeed the case.